# How do I prevent this Integer expectation error?

Tags: python

I'm making a simple little snake game as coding practice.
While trying to add the tail character to the window, I get this error. I know that I am not giving it integers, but I do not know what to do differently in order to.

Here is the error:

```
    line 56, in <module>
    w.addch(tail[0], tail[1], ' ')
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Here is the part generating error:

```
else:
        tail = snake.pop()
        w.addch(tail[0], tail[1], ' ')
```

Heres the full code:

```
import random
import curses

s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x = sw/4
snk_y = sh/2
snake = [
    [snk_y, snk_x],
    [snk_y, snk_x-1],
    [snk_y, snk_x-2]
]

food = [sh/2, sw/2]
w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)

key = curses.KEY_RIGHT

while True:
    next_key = w.getch()
    key = key if next_key == -1 else next_key

    if snake[0][0] in [0, sh] or snake[0][1] in [0, sw] or snake[0] in snake[1:]:
        curses.endwin()
        quit()

    new_head = [snake[0][0], snake[0][1]]

    if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
        new_head[0] += 1
    if key == curses.KEY_UP:
        new_head[0] -= 1
    if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
        new_head[1] += 1
    if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
        new_head[1] -= 1
    
    snake.insert(0, new_head)

    if snake[0] == food:
        food = None
        while food is None:
            nf = [
                random.randinit(1, sh-1),
                random.randinit(1, sw-1)
            ]
            food = nf if nf not in snake else None
        w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
    else:
        tail = snake.pop()
        w.addch(tail[0], tail[1], ' ')
    
    w.addch(snake[0][0], snake[0][1], curses.ACS_CKBOARD)
```

I cant think of a way to be more direct so this is me filling the text requirements.
reference for code?:
s = screen, snk_x/y = Snake x/y, sw/sh = screen width/height, w = window.
If I can be anymore clear let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addch` expects `int`. But division of integers in python 3 returns `float`.

You can:

- convert the numbers to int `w.addch(int(food[0]), int(food[1]), curses.ACS_PI)`
- or you can use `//` instead of `/` to do integer division

Comment: I did this and it worked. any chance you know why i get a random has no randinit module error, btw i do not have anything named random that pycharm could be loading instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try just casting the values to integers using `int()` as follows:

```
w.addch(int(tail[0]), int(tail[1]), ' ')
```